# How to effectively debug constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, constexpr, c++14

In C++14 we get [upgraded version of `constexpr`](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html) meaning that now it will be possible to use loops, if-statements and switches.
Recursion is already possible as in C++11.

I understand that `constexpr` functions/code should be quite simple, but still the question arise: **how to effectively debug it?**

Even in "*The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition*" there is a sentence that debugging can be hard.

Comment: Same way as you debug template metaprograms :-)

Comment: Also note that `constexpr` functions don't *have* to be evaluated statically. If you provide a non-constexpr argument, you just have a normal function call, which you should be able to debug.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: @Mehrdad: You should be able to put a breakpoint on a `constexpr` function to break the compiler :)

Comment: We gotta have a `g++ --gdb` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two important aspects for debugging `constexpr` functions.

**1) Make sure they compute the correct result**

Here you can use regular unit-testing, asserts or a runtime debugger to step through your code. There is nothing new compared to testing regular functions here.

**2) Make sure they can be evaluated at compile-time**

This can be tested by evaluating the function as the right-hand side of a `constexpr` variable assignment.

```
constexpr auto my_var = my_fun(my_arg);
```

In order for this to work, `my_fun` can a) only have compile-time constant expression as actual arguments. I.e. `my_arg` is a literal (builtin or user-defined) or a previously computed `constexpr` variable or a template parameter, etc, and b) it can only call `constexpr` functions in its implementation (so no virtuals, no lambda expressions, etc.).

**Note**: it is very hard to actually debug the compiler's implementation of code generation during the compile-time evaluation of your `constexpr` function. You would have to attach a debugger to your compiler and actually be able to interpret the code path. Maybe some future version of Clang will let you do this, but this is not feasible with current technology.

Fortunately, because you can decouple the runtime and compile-time behavior of `constexpr` functions, debugging them isn't half as hard as debugging template metaprograms (which can only be run at compile-time).

Comment: Great! so basically you can use "normal" debugging at runtime and then only make sure it gets computed properly in compile-time. I hope that constexpr will make metaprogramming much easier. I think it is a great feature of C++1y

Comment: @fen yes that's exactly how I do it. And it is much, much easier than template-metaprogramming. E.g., a `constexpr` `switch`-statement is equivalent to several class template specializations in TMP. It greatly reduces the number of lines of code that one has to maintain, and you always have the option to run the same code with runtime parameters.

Comment: I've found a great article here: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/07/want-speed-use-constexpr-meta.html it describes how constexpr makes life simpler.

Comment: I'm a fan of `static_assert` for this. It checks the value _and_ requires it to be computed at compile time.  Example: `static_assert(my_fun(my_arg)==42", "my_fun(my_arg) failure")`

Comment: @MarshallClow `static_assert` has the drawback that it canonly work at compiletime, whereas the `throw` trick in the link by @fen alsoworks at runtime

Comment: @MarshallClow sorry, I meant [this blog](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/compile-time-computations/), instead of the one mentioned by fen.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I wrote on 3 April '15 is clearly wrong.  I can't understand what I was thinking.

Here is the "real" answer - the method I use now.

a) write your constexpr function as you normally would.  So far it doesn't work.

b) when the function is invoked at compile time - compilation fails with nothing more than a message to the effect "invalid constexpr" function.  This makes it hard to know what the problem actually is.

c) Make small test program which calls the function with parameters known only at runtime.  Run your test program with the debugger.  You'll find that you can trace through the function in the normal manner.

It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, you can try [this](https://github.com/saarraz/static-print/blob/master/README.md)

and there is a [introduce](https://youtu.be/61w4LbQ0fzU?list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1) about it

Answer (score 0):

If by debugging you mean "make it known that a certain expression is not of a desired value", you could check it at runtime

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int test(int x){ return x> 0 ? x : (throw std::domain_error("wtf")); }

int main()
{
  test(42);
  std::cout<< "42\n";
  test(-1);
  std::cout<< "-1\n";
}
```